# Handling devise registration errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've subclassed the devise RegistrationsController for creating new users and added some logic before calling the superclass's 'create' method.  So, something like:

> class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
>
> def create
>
> super end

I can tell if the superclass encountered an error by checking resource.errors.nil?.  However, I want to distinguish between different errors.  For instance, I want to do something different if the error is "Email has already been taken" versus some other error return.

I can parse the string, but that seems fragile to me.  What if some future upgrade of ActiveRecord or Devise changes the string?  What if the string get's localized in some way I don't expect?

Is anyone handling error processing in devise more gracefully than string parsing?

Answer (score 0):

you can modify devise.en.yml for any default errors

Comment: some elaboration would help the OP

Comment: in config/locals/devise.en.yml file there are some default errors that come with devise, modifying it may get your work done...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the [`devise_error_messages`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb#L11) helper is just running through the errors attached to whatever you have assigned as your `resource` object (whatever user model you ran the install generator on).

Now, instead of just printing out the error messages in the helper, you could access their keys in a controller method, as well:

```
 # in RegistrationsController
 def create
   build_resource
   unless resource.valid?
     if resource.errors.has_key?(:my_error_key)
       # do something
     end
   end
 end
```

This is just an example, of course, but hopefully it illustrates the approach you might take.

Answer (score 0):

With Rails validation errors the devil is in the @details.

A typical validation error on presence looks like this:

```
> @user.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe7e8f01234 @base=#<User id: nil, 
email: "someone@else.mail", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
@messages={:password=>["can't be blank"], :email=>[]},
@details={:password=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

As you see, the failed validation is accurately described in @details of the ActiveModel Error object.

There is even a short hand method in Rails that makes it easy to test for specific validation errors:

```
@user.errors.added? :password, :blank
```

If the password is left blank, this will return true.

More about added? in the Ruby on Rails API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-added-3F